# vim how to break new line without entering Insert mode

Tags: vim

I have a few lines of codes that are too that I would like to break into 2 lines at certain location.

So instead of moving to the position then presse `I` to insert mode then `Enter` to break line then finally `ESc` back.

Is there way I can do it easier in normal mode only?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is that "certain location"? Do you decide that for each case individually or does it follow some rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define some simple mapping for it:

```
" <C-Enter>     Insert single / [count] newline.
nnoremap <C-CR> i<CR><Esc>
```

Note that `<C-CR>` probably only works in GVIM, not in a terminal; choose a different key if necessary.

Here's an additional mapping that keeps the cursor on the original line:

```
" <C-S-Enter>   Append single / [count] newline.
function! s:AppendCRSetPos()
    keepjumps call setpos("''", getpos('.'))
    return ''
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <SID>(AppendCRSetPos) <SID>AppendCRSetPos()
nnoremap <script> <C-S-CR> <SID>(AppendCRSetPos)i<CR><Esc>g``
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my .vimrc

```
nnoremap S i<cr><esc>^mwgk:silent! s/\v +$//<cr>:noh<cr>`w
```

Which will split the line on pressing capital S.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. that works too, But I accepted the earlier one simply because it was earlier. Great answer too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a vim key for that:

```
r<Enter>
```

Comment: I think r is for replace.

Comment: It works only on a space, because it's replacing the space with the new line.